# Transform hamburger icon when clicking link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a hamburger menu where an overlay menu div fills the screen when clicking the hamburger icon (which is animated to a cross when clicked).

I want the hamburger to change back to it's original state when clicking any menu link at the same time as it hides the overlay div.

Is there an easy way to implement this in the menu links?

```js
function funcToggle() {
  $("#Overlay").toggle("slow");
}

function funcHide() {
  $("#Overlay").toggle("slow");
}

document.querySelector("#nav-toggle")
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
  });
```

```css
#nav-toggle span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 18px;
  background: #1098fe;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -5px;
}

#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -5px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before,
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #fe0000;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: #fe0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show" class="show">
  <nav>
    <a id="nav-toggle" href="#" onclick="funcToggle()"><span></span></a>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="Overlay" name="Overlay" class="overlay">
  <ul class="hamburger_menu">
    <li><a href="#top" onclick="funcHide()">TOP</a></li>
    <li><a href="#newsletter" onclick="funcHide()">NEWSLETTER</a></li>
    <li><a href="#videos" onclick="funcHide()">VIDEOS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" onclick="funcHide()">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Depending on how it is animated, I would recommend CSS animation. Setting animation styles on the base class for the hamburger will allow it to animate back to original when you remove the "opened" class.

Comment: Ah, added the CSS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix jQuery/JS, stick to one.

```
// cache DOM elements as jquery objects
// adding $ to jquery objects is a good practice
var $overlay = $('#overlay'),
    $nav = $('#nav-toggle'),
    $links = $('#overlay a');

// descriptive names
function funcToggleNav() {
  $overlay.toggle("slow");
}

function funcToggleBurger () {
  $nav.toggleClass("active");
}

$nav.on("click", function () {
  funcToggleBurger();
  funcToggleNav();
});

$links.on("click", function () {
  funcToggleBurger();
  funcToggleNav();
})
```

Example: [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/timoyojipa/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: Check my jsbin example I've posted above, that should represent what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/2jys1dhs/

```js
$('ul.hamburger_menu li a').click(function(){
  $("#Overlay").toggle("slow");
  $('a#nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
});

$("#nav-toggle").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $("#Overlay").toggle("slow");
});
```

```css
#nav-toggle span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 18px;
  background: #1098fe;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -5px;
}

#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -5px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before,
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #fe0000;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: #fe0000;
}

.overlay{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show" class="show">
  <nav>
    <a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="Overlay" name="Overlay" class="overlay" >
  <ul class="hamburger_menu">
    <li><a href="#top">TOP</a></li>
    <li><a href="#newsletter">NEWSLETTER</a></li>
    <li><a href="#videos">VIDEOS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've used `jQuery` click event rather than `HTML` `onclick` method.
For initial hiding of please use `CSS` `display:none;` property.

Hope this will help you.